# Attribute information not showing in Silverlight viewer popup

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, viewer, arcgis-silverlight-viewer

I have feature service which I am accessing through a Silverlight viewer. The popups contain all the available fields (about 40), most of which have coded value domains. Looking at the popup, these fields appear blank. If I click on the `Edit Values` button, the fields' existing attribute information appears (which I can see in ArcMap).

This might be an issue with version 3.1 of the viewer; similar issues are mentioned on the [ESRI](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/90607-Popups-only-showing-header-no-other-attribute-info) [forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/54549-Coded-Domain-Values-in-Pop-ups-and-Attribute-Table). I have not had this problem before, and I could see the values in the viewer three days ago. The only thing that's different is I had to republish the service after making cosmetic changes to the map. The data, field aliases etc all stayed the same.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @nmtoken The question was in the title: The attribute information was not showing up in the popup in the Silverlight viewer. I don't regard this question as valid anymore as Silverlight is dead and it was most likely some issue on the company's network/browser cache.

Comment: The title is a statement, not a question.  A question might be what's wrong with my code?, or is this a browser issue?  In any case I couldn't determine what the definitive question was so, that's why I added the comment.

Comment: @nmtoken Look at the related questions and see how many questions are expressed as statements, but are clearly questions. If it's bothering you, feel free to rephrase the question with a question mark.